# IntervalTree in Guava

Tags: java, algorithm, guava, intervals, interval-tree

I am working with Guava's Range class for processing intervals. I wanted to know if it is possible to find the closest interval from a set of intervals to a given point/interval by using some of the Guava's collection containers ?

I tried searching for interval trees in Java and here is what I found. I would prefer to do it by using one of the Guava classes if possible.

http://picard.sourceforge.net/javadoc/net/sf/picard/util/IntervalTree.html
http://tribble.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/org/broad/tribble/index/interval/IntervalTree.java

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what "the closest interval" is for a point?  For an interval?  I don't understand how you can have a closest interval for a point.  A point is either in a Range or not?  Is "the closest interval" the interval which contains a point and the smallest difference between the point and the Range's endpoints?

Comment: For example is we have the following intervals [1, 10], [15, 20] then [15, 20] would be closest interval to the point 14 and [1, 10] would be the closest interval to 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava doesn't provide this, though you might be able to build such a thing on top of a [`RangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html) by finding the first range before and after a given point.

But generally, Guava `Range`s know *nothing* about distances, metrics, or anything except the comparison ordering of a type.  They don't know that `10` is closer to `11` than `15`.

Comment: Finding the first range before and after a given point should do the trick. How do I accomplish it in RangeSet ? Do I make a pseudo border around the point and search for overlaps, or is there some direct way ?

Comment: `RangeSet.subRangeSet(Range.greaterThan(point)).span().lowerEndpoint()` should give you the endpoint of the first range to the right of the point.

Comment: Glancing at `RangeSet`, I'm curious why `C` is bounded by raw `Comparable` rather than `Comparable<? super C>`. **Edit:** I guess I should ask that about `Range` instead.

Comment: Ah just found the note about supporting "ungenerified (pre-JDK1.5) data types" for now - understood.